# How can I record the identity of turtles another turtle interacts with?

Tags: netlogo

My model involves one turtle surveying the area and it should keep track of the ID/ 'who' of the turtles it bumps into. Importantly, the surveyor could potentially record the same ID/ 'who' twice but I'm not sure how to implement that memory side of things.

```
breed[boats boat]

boats-own [
  my-neighbors
  num-neighbors
count-neighbors]


to setup
  clear-all
  crt 100 [
    move-to one-of patches with [ not any? turtles-here ]
    
  ]
  
  crt 1 [set breed boats
  set count-neighbors 0
  ]

  reset-ticks
end

to go 
  ask turtles [
    fd 1
  ]
  
  ask boats [
    survey
  ]
  tick 
end 

to survey
 
    set my-neighbors (other turtles) in-radius 3
    set num-neighbors count my-neighbors
    set count-neighbors [who] of my-neighbors
   
end
```

UPDATE
In light of the answer below I came up with the following which also records when the interaction took place by creating a new time variable.

```
breed[boats boat]

boats-own [
  my-neighbors
  num-neighbors
id-neighbors
survey-time]

turtles-own [
  time
]


to setup
  clear-all
  crt 10 [
    move-to one-of patches with [ not any? turtles-here ]
    
  ]
  
  crt 1 [
    set breed boats
    set shape "circle"
    set id-neighbors []
    set survey-time []
  ]

  reset-ticks
end

to go 
  ask turtles [
    fd 1
    set time ticks 
  ]
  
  ask boats [
    survey
  ]
  tick 
end 

to survey
 
    set my-neighbors (other turtles-here )  
    set num-neighbors count my-neighbors
    set id-neighbors (sentence id-neighbors [who] of my-neighbors )
    set survey-time (sentence survey-time [time] of my-neighbors )
   
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are always setting count-neighbors to the list of all its current neighbors, but this list is cleared and made anew with each tick. Instead of that, you can use primitives like `sentence` to combine the old list of `count-neighbors` with the new list you are generating this iteration and set the new list of `count-neighbors` to be this combined list.

```
  set count-neighbors (sentence count-neighbors [who] of my-neighbors )
```

I also initialised your `count-neighbors` as an empty list rather than as 0, since 0 is already a turtle who so that would give you false information

```
  crt 1 [set breed boats
    set count-neighbors []
  ]
```

To check if the memory is working as intended, you can use `inspect one-of boats` in the command center and see how each new entry gets added to the end of the list.

---

Edit for followup question

Your solution here definitely works. Allow me a few suggestions for it as well:

There is not need to create the `time` variable, each turtle can already access the `ticks` global variable

```
  set id-neighbors (sentence id-neighbors [who] of my-neighbors )
  set survey-time (sentence survey-time [ticks] of my-neighbors )
```

As an alternative, this one creates a list of lists, with each item containing the turtle that was encountered and the time when it was encountered. Slightly harder to work with but clear at a glance which values belong together.

```
set id-neighbors (sentence id-neighbors [list who ticks] of my-neighbors )
```

Comment: Great, I didn't know about `sentence`. This may be better suited for another question but could you record the tick when the boat sees a turtle?

Comment: I think I have the answer to my second question but just repurposing your answer. I've updated my question now so this is visible.

Comment: @adkane I edited my answer with some suggestions about recording time, but yours works as well